# Java Error when trying to start stardog server

Tags: java, stardog

When I try to start my stardog-server, my terminal shows me following Java-Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/complexible/stardog/cli/admin/CLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have no idea why this keeps happening, because I have gotten my stardom-server to run before, but today it started showing me this Error.
Does anybody have an idea about why this keeps happening?

I'm working on OSX Mavericks (if that helps anyone)

Comment: Did you finally get a solution? I have now the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the classpath.

Searching for this I found [this exchange](https://groups.google.com/a/clarkparsia.com/forum/#!topic/stardog/twVbtgU_ycM):

> This is due to a bug in the stardog.bat script. If you add a semicolon to line 21 so that it reads 
> 'set CLASSPATH=%HOMEDIR%\client\api*;%HOMEDIR%\client\cli*;%HOMEDIR%\client\http*;%HOMEDIR%\client\snarl*;%HOMEDIR%\pack\client*;%SLF4J_JARS%'
>  this problem will be fixed.

Comment: In my version of stardom the stardom.bat file is already up to date. Doesn't seem to be the solution to this problem!

Comment: sorry to hear that; The message you get is java telling you that it can't find a class. This is usually due to classpath errors. Other options are wrong path settings for stardog or really missing files.